# 2 outputs when calculating Cohen's d

Tags: r

I've just tried to calculate Cohen's d in R with the following formula:

```
mean1 <- mean(Meaningfulness[df$age<=22],na.rm=TRUE)
mean2 <- mean(Meaningfulness[df age>=22],na.rm=TRUE)
sd1 <- sd(Meaningfulness[df$age<=22],na.rm=TRUE)
sd2 <- sd(Meaningfulness[df$age>=22],na.rm=TRUE)

pooled <- sqrt((sd1^2 + sd2^2) / 2


d <- (mean1-mean2)/(pooled)
```

Just to be sure I have compared 2 outputs with an online "cohen's d calculator". The Cohen's ds I've calculated differs by 0.04 and.003 from the online calculator.
Any suggestions on what might be wrong with my code? Every help is appreciated!! :)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please provide a reference to the particular online calculator you used as well.

Comment: Rounding?  I also notice that observations with `df$age == 22` will contribute to both groups.  That's almost certainly not correct.  I think you have a typo in line 2 of your code.

Comment: Is it `mean2` - `mean1`?

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all your answers already. @MrFlick the online calculator I used was this one: https://statistikguru.de/rechner/cohens-d.html
When I compare my results
Mean 1 =  4.979567; sd1 = 0,7342572
Mean 2 = 5,147837; sd2 = 0,7683255
The difference is worse when I feed the online calculator with the output of my t-test (t = -2.6052, df = 393);

could this be because I remove the n.a. in the manual calculation of Cohen's d, but not in the t-test?If so - is there actually a possibility to remove the n.a. in the t-test?
I just noticed I also get different means for group 1 in the ttest

Comment: @Limey oh your right! I see the typo. Thankfully the typo just happened when I edited my question - in Rstudio I got it right ;) 
Actually it is not df$age==22 but df$age<= and df$age>= so that shouldn't be the problem...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.